# Запуск скрипта в определённое время

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть код, в котором некоторая часть должна запускаться в опредёленное время. Читал про cron, но как я понял, он для linux'a. Какие существуют модули для решения моей задачи на python?

Comment: На Windows есть [`at`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb726974(v=technet.10)#scheduling-tasks-with-the-at-utility).

Comment: меня интересуют модули для python

Comment: Есть модуль `shedule`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery — один из самых популярных проектов для решения подобных задач в мире python и Django на данный момент, но есть и другие проекты для этой цели. Это планировщик задач для проектов на python. Может выстраивать задачи в очередь, запускать в определенное время или во время простоя компьютера.

http://www.celeryproject.org/

В `asyncio` [есть функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_at) для запуска корутины в определенное время `call_at`. Но проект Ваш тогда должен поддерживать asyncio.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, есть модули [sched](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sched.html#scheduler-objects) и  [timer](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#timer-objects), например.

Например, запуск функции (например, start_prg) на следующий день в 1:00:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

x=datetime.today()
y=x.replace(day=x.day+1, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t=y-x

secs=delta_t.seconds+1

def start_prg():
    print "Start programm"
    #...

t = Timer(secs, start_prg)
t.start()
```